# LINQ Grouping to same recipient

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

i want to Group a List of Mails to their recipients.

The `lstMails` List is a `List<MailModel>`

MailModel has a Property which is
string[] To.

for example there could be 5 mails in this List.

- Mail1.To = ["nico.test@test.de"]
- Mail2.To = ["nico.test@test.de", "nico.frank@test.de"]
- Mail3.To = ["nico.jeff@test.de"]
- Mail4.To = ["nico.star@test.de", "nico.frank@test.de"]
- Mail5.To = ["nico.jeff@test.de"]

i would like to get a list for each Mail Recipient.

So for example

- "lstNicoTest" = [ Mail1, Mail2 ]
- "lstNicoJeff" = [ Mail3, Mail5 ]
- "lstNicoFrank" = [ Mail2, Mail4 ]
- "lstNicoStar" = [ Mail5 ]

at best it would be a `ForEach(List<MailModel> list in lstMails.GroupBy(-----))`

i dont know i have been googling around, but the problem is if i Group By it only checks if arrays are the Same, basicly if .To is `["reci1", "reci"] == ["reci1", "reci"]` it doesnt not "copy" them basicly

if i did not provide sufficent information im sorry, im here to edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this gives the desired result:

```
var mailsByRecipient = (from m in lstMails
                  from recipient in m.To
                  select new { m, recipient } into s
                  group s by s.recipient into g
                  select new { recipient = g.Key, mails = g.Select(x => x.m) })
                  .ToList();
```

It returns a list of every unique email recipient, with the list of `MailModel`s it's in.

It achieves that by first creating a cartesian product of each recipient with it's respective `MailModel` (into `s`), and uses that to group by recipient (into `g`).

The last select is purely aesthetical, creating a new object that contains the properties `recipient` and `mails`. I find it quirky to work with `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` directly.

Comment: This worked like a Charm ! and i have to say besides the Naming which i like to be more "readable" in Linq, its exactly like i wanted. Even the select new is realy helpfull have to note me on that ! this query realy motivated me to get my head more into Linq !. Great stuff

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch all recipients, then distinct them and then filter `lstMails` for the user.

Something like:

```
lstMails
  .SelectMany(mail => mail.To)
  .Distinct()
  .Select(user => lstMails.Where(mail => mail.To.Contains(user))
```